# Adding JTextArea in front of image

Tags: java, image, swing, jtextarea

I would like to add JTextArea in front/on top of an image. Whenever I try to add it to the frame positioning it as BorderLayout.CENTER/TOP etc. the text is added above the image. When I have tried frame.add(textArea), the whole image won't display.

Should I be adding JTextArea inside my ComponentImage class?

This is my code:

**GUI Class:**

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

 public class GUILab {

private Image image;
public JTextArea textArea;
public JPanel bottomPanel;
public JTextField jtf;
public JButton updateButton;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");

    Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();
    int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    int screenHeight = screenSize.height;

    int frameWidth = screenWidth / 2;
    int frameHeight = screenHeight / 2;

    frame.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    frame.setTitle("");
    frame.setLocation(100, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //Call image
    ComponentImage image = new ComponentImage();
    frame.add(image, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //TextField: adding to bottomPanel, then add bottomPanel to frame
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(8, 20);
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextField jtf = new JTextField("Test", 25);
    JButton updateButton = new JButton("Update");
    bottomPanel.add(jtf);
    bottomPanel.add(updateButton);

    updateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {            
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            textArea.append(jtf.getText()+"\n");
            System.out.println(jtf.getText());
        }
    });

    frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //frame.add(textArea);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**ComponentImage class:**

```
 package test;

 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import javax.swing.JComponent;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Image;
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class ComponentImage extends JComponent {

    private Image image; 
    private int compWidth=400;
    private int compHeight=300;
    public GUILab guilab;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    image=new ImageIcon("bg1.jpg").getImage();

    g.drawImage(image, 0,0,null);

    g.drawString("Test", 100, 120);

    }

public Dimension getPreferredSize() { 
    return new Dimension(compWidth, compHeight);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** To clarify: when text is entered into the TextField, and the Update button is clicked, that text should appear on top of the image

Comment: You need to add your text area into your `ComponentImage` object. Something like `image.add(new JScrollPane(textArea))`. Also `ComponentImage extends JPanel` would also be better.

Comment: This is horrible `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    image=new ImageIcon("bg1.jpg").getImage();` replace it with `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g);` The `image` itself should be declared as an attribute of the class and loaded **once** in the constructor or an initialization method. Also note that the preferred size of the `ComponentImage` should be based on a combination of the image size and the text area that is added to it (the larger of the width & height). I personally would tend to write the text direct to the image unless the user ..

Comment: .. needs to edit or otherwise enter it into the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

```
g.drawImage(image, 0,0,null);
```

You are drawing the image at its actual size. If this is your real requirement then just use a JLabel with an ImageIcon. The JLabel by default displays the image at its preferred size and will calculate the preferred size of the label as the size of the image.

If your requirement is to scale the image as the frame size changes, then yes you will need to do custom painting but you would then use:

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
```

to do dynamic scaling of the image.

> When I have tried frame.add(textArea), the whole image won't display.

When using a BorderLayout and you don't specify a constraint then `BorderLayout.CENTER` is assumed. You can't add two components to the CENTER of the frame.

So you need to add the text area to the image panel (either your custom component or the JLabel:

```
JPanel background = new ComponentImage();
background.setLayout(...);
background.add( textArea );
```

Note if you do your custom painting on a JPanel the default layout is set to a FlowLayout. If you do the custom painting on a JComponent it doesn't have a default layout manager so you will need to set the layout manager.